# Please tell me how to make specific query MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a documents with grades in collection **grades**

```
grade1=({letter: 'excellent', num: 5})
db.grade.save(grade1)

grade2=({letter: 'good', num: 4})
db.grade.save(grade2)

grade3=({letter: 'satisfactory', num: 3})
db.grade.save(grade3)

grade4=({letter: 'passed'})
db.grade.save(grade4)

grade5=({letter: 'not passed'})
db.grade.save(grade5)

grade6=({letter: 'absenteeism'})
db.grade.save(grade6)
```

I have a documents with subjects in collection **subject**

```
sub1=({name: 'name1'})
db.subject.save(sub1)

sub2=({name: 'name2'})
db.subject.save(sub2)

sub3=({name: 'name3'})
db.subject.save(sub3)

sub4=({name: 'name4'})
db.subject.save(sub4)

sub5=({name: 'name5'})
db.subject.save(sub5)

sub6=({name: 'name6'})
db.subject.save(sub6)
```

I also have documents that record students' turn-in of subjects. They're kept in the collection  **statement**

```
ved1=({subject: new DBRef ('subject', pred3._id), date:'01.05.2022', teacher: new DBRef ('teacher', teacher1._id), 
group: new DBRef ('group', group2._id), 
control: [{name: 'student1', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)}, 
{name: 'student2', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)}, 
{name: 'student3', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade3._id)}, 
{name: 'student4', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)},
{name: 'student5', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)},
{name: 'student6', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade3._id)},
{name: 'student7', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)},
{name: 'student8', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)},
{name: 'student9', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)},
{name: 'student10', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade5._id)}]})   //---
db.statement.save(ved1)



ved2=({subject: new DBRef ('subject', pred2._id), date:'02.05.2022', teacher: new DBRef ('teacher', teacher1._id), 
group: new DBRef ('group', group2._id), 
control: [{name: 'student1', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)}, 
{name: 'student2', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)}, 
{name: 'student3', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)}, 
{name: 'student4', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)},
{name: 'student5', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)},
{name: 'student6', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)},
{name: 'student7', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade6._id)}, //---
{name: 'student8', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade6._id)},    //---
{name: 'student9', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)},
{name: 'student10', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)}]})
db.statement.save(ved2)

ved3=({subject: new DBRef ('subject', pred1._id), date:'03.05.2022', teacher: new DBRef ('teacher', teacher2._id), 
group: new DBRef ('group', group2._id), 
control: [{name: 'student1', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade4._id)}, 
{name: 'student2', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade4._id)}, 
{name: 'student3', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade4._id)}, 
{name: 'student4', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade4._id)},
{name: 'student5', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade4._id)},
{name: 'student6', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade5._id)},          //---
{name: 'student7', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade6._id)},  //---
{name: 'student8', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade4._id)},
{name: 'student9', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade4._id)},
{name: 'student10', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade4._id)}]})
db.statement.save(ved3)

ved4=({subject: new DBRef ('subject', pred5._id), date:'04.05.2022', teacher: new DBRef ('teacher', teacher4._id), 
group: new DBRef ('group', group2._id), 
control: [{name: 'student1', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade5._id)}, //---
{name: 'student2', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)}, 
{name: 'student3', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)}, 
{name: 'student4', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)},
{name: 'student5', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)},
{name: 'student6', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)},
{name: 'student7', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)},
{name: 'student8', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade2._id)},
{name: 'student9', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)},
{name: 'student10', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)}]})
db.statement.save(ved4)

ved5=({subject: new DBRef ('subject', pred5._id), date:'08.05.2022', teacher: new DBRef ('teacher', teacher4._id), 
group: new DBRef ('group', group2._id), 
control: [{name: 'student1', grade: new DBRef ('grade', grade1._id)} //---
db.statement.save(ved5)
```

It is necessary to bring out students who study without arrears. That is, those students who only have grades **excellent, good, satisfactory or passed**. It is worth noting that students can retake a failed exam. For example in **ved5 student1** corrected his/her grade to positive, even though he/she has a negative grade in **ved4**. I.e. probably for this should take into account the **date** of the **statement**. Please advise how to do this. I still haven't figured out how to solve this problem, but if there are intermediate steps, I will post it here. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

**EDIT**: including 'subject'

```
db.veds.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "dateIso": {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$date", format: "%d.%m.%Y"}}
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$control"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "grades",
      localField: "control.grade",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "grades"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {dateIso: -1}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {student: "$control.name", subject: "$subject"},
      finalGrade: {$first: {$arrayElemAt: ["$grades", 0]}}
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.student",
      finalGrades: {$push: "$finalGrade"},
      allowedSubjects: {$sum: {$cond: [{$in: ["$finalGrade.letter",
                ["excellent", "good", "satisfactory", "passed"]]},
                  1, 0]}}
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {$eq: ["$allowedSubjects", {$size: "$finalGrades"}]}
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U6EuSv7TtIO).

First we create an `ISODate`, then we bring the grades from the grades collection, then we can `$unwind` and `$sort` the student to get the latest grade first, now we can `$group` the students by subjects so we will only have one (last) grade per student per subject. Now we can `$group` by student and count the number of allowed grades. Last part is to `$match` only students which their number of allowed subject is equal to the number of final grades.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your help! Sorry to be cheeky, but could you help with a query if only the last grade for a certain subject is supposed to count. That is, if the grade was received later, it should not affect all grades, but only a specific subject (change it). And in the end, display students who have only "excellent", "good", "satisfactory", "passed" grades among all subjects. Sorry for the complexity

Comment: The answer is already doing this. Last grade only. ["excellent", "good", "satisfactory", "passed"] only.

Comment: Please look again on the playground link that I attached to the answer

Comment: Updated according to your comment

Comment: If it works for you please accept it, so it will be easier for others to find it.